# Height of BootStrap elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having trouble understanding a basic BootStrap Construct. I can control the width of the content by specifying the `col-xs-**`, `col-lg-**` types classes. These are linked to the width of the display.
How do I control the height of a particular row?

Say I want one row of columns to span 400 pixels vertically, irrespective of data inside it. How is that accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap does not provide such a class. You need to specify `height: 400px;` in `style` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably don't want to apply it to the entire grid system, have a class on your .container where you want this and apply the height through css on that class.